# Relationship tables between Product and Store magento 1.9

Tags: product, magento-1.9.3.6

I am importing products programmatically. I assign store and website id to products. Kindly look code as below

```
$product->setStoreId(0);
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(0,1));
```

for website I found the table: catalog_product_website. I want to see the relationship table for product and store.

Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct relation between products and store views.
There is a relation between product attributes and store views.
For example, a product can have a name in one store view and another one in another store view.
The relation between product attributes and stores is defined in the tables that start with `catalog_product_entity_`.
The field `entity_id` is the product id and `store_id` is the store id (obviously).  `attribute_id` is the id of the attribute.

You will find records with `store_id = 0`. This means that those are the default values. In case there is no value specified for an attribute in a certain store view, this default value will be used.

Comment: So, If I want to see products at WebPOS screen , I need to add $product->setStoreId(1); Because currently products are not diplaying

Comment: I have no idea what WebPOS is

Comment: WebPOS is the magestore POS plugin: https://www.magestore.com/omnichannel-retail

Comment: sorry, I have no idea how that works

Comment: ok. thanks. no problem. Thanks for help it was helpful. A small thing but very important I thought.